# Binding xaml property visibility to ViewModel, control with button

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I have a `StackLayout` property in xmal like shown below:

```
   <StackLayout x:Name="_infoView"
                 Margin="0,10,0,10"
                 BackgroundColor="Black"
                 IsVisible="{Binding State}"/>
```

and a binding bool variable in ViewModel

```
    private Boolean _state = true;
    public Boolean State
    {
        get { return _state; }
        set { }
    }
```

I have a button in my xmal and would like to control the visibility of my StackLayout, So I did something like this:

```
        <Button x:Name="CloseButton"
                Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.Column="3"
                Command="{Binding CloseWindowCommand}"/>
```

and in ViewModel

```
CloseWindowCommand = new Command(CloseWindowTapped, CanCloseWindowTapped);

public ICommand CloseWindowCommand { get; set; }
public void CloseWindowTapped()
{
     State = false;
}
public bool CanCloseWindowTapped()
{
    return true;
}
```

I'd assume, by tap on the CloseButton, my StackLayout will gone... but it is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ViewModel should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface for informing View about changes.

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // Implementing INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
    }        

    // In the setter of property raise event to inform view about changes
    private Boolean _state = true;
    public Boolean State
    {
        get 
        { 
            return _state; 
        }
        set 
        { 
            _state = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the simple and straight forward answer! I'm still getting to know MVVM model, this is very helpful!